# How can I effectively place and anchor a 2D image in an augmented reality(AR)environment using the front-facing camera with ARCore for native Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have successfully placed a 3D model, and it's working fine. However, I am facing issues when trying to add a 2D model using the front-facing camera [Facing Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wahme.jpg)

I have added iOS image below for the reference. [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgyWV.png)

Comment: For compatibility and readability, please put the actual question in the question body. For the title, just use a short summary.